# Cypress: Object.values no devuelve lista de valores de un objeto

Tags: javascript, objeto, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo, cypress

En cypress de un programa que estoy haciendo necesito acumular pares de elementos en un objeto (values), para luego crear una matriz con esos elementos. El tema es que al ver lo que pasa en la consola me doy cuenta que Object.values() por alguna razón no extrae los valores que están dentro del objeto. Por eso, lo que espero que termine siendo una matriz termina siendo un array vacío...

Código de cypress:

```
 it('Al tocar dos cartas distintas el tablero sigue con la misma cantidad de cartas', () => {
    cy.get('#jugar').click();
    const paresCartas = obtenerParesCartas();
    console.log(paresCartas);
    console.log(Object.values(paresCartas));
});

function obtenerParesCartas() {
  const pares = {};
  cy.get('#tablero').find('.reverso').each(imagen => {
    const referenciaImagen = (imagen.attr('src').replace('src/img/', '').replace('.png', ''));

    if (pares[referenciaImagen]) {
      pares[referenciaImagen].push(imagen);
    } else {
      pares[referenciaImagen] = [imagen];
    }
  });
  return pares;
}
```

`paresCartas` es la variable que almacena el objeto.

Parte del código html para que se entienda de donde sale #tablero, .reverso y src:

```
<div id="tablero" class="col-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="carta col">
          <img src="" class="reverso rounded" />
        </div>
```

(Hay también un script que hace que al dar click en Jugar se agreguen direcciones en el src de las cartas como por ejemplo: 'src/img/javascript-logo.png'). No lo agrego para que no sea tan larga la pregunta sin necesidad.)

[image: Consola del programa]

En la imagen anterior se puede apreciar lo que da como resultado la consola. La línea 17 hace referencia al `console.log(paresCartas)`, y el array vacío de la línea 18 hace referencia a `console.log(Object.values(paresCartas))`.

[image: Muestra elemento de objeto]

Finalmente en la última imágen muestro que el objeto creado `paresCartas` tiene en los valores efectivamente elementos del programa, los cuales espero que me pase a una matriz.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no has cometido ningún error, simplemente que muchas veces al hacer un find() la respuesta es `s.fn.init [prevObject: s.fn.init(1)]` , lo cual significa que no ha encontrado ningún elemento con dichas consiciones y el prevObject está vacío.

Sabiendo esto, es probable que `Object.values()` te devuelva `[]` ya que todos los values existentes son campos vacíos.

Espero que esto te haya solucionado el problema.